# Detect the difference between a swipe-to-delete button and a delete button made in Edit mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I currently have a UITableView set up to enable swipe-to-delete (a swipe shows the Delete button). I also have an Edit button which, when pushed, slides in the red deletion circles for each cell. Tapping one of those circles causes the Delete button to show as if I'd swiped the cell.

I'd like to detect whether the Delete button was created via one of the red circles (i.e. in Edit mode) or by directly swiping on the cell (reason being I'd like the user to confirm if they didn't come in via Edit mode, since they can potentially lose a lot of data if they mistapped it).

I've tried the `isEditing` property of the tableView, but that's `YES` however I got to the delete button. Is there a more nuanced way to detect this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would confirm in both cases; in edit mode, it's also possible to make a mistake (selecting an extra item for deletion).

Comment: It's not a batch deletion mode, so in editing more, you already need to tap the red circle, then the delete button. That seems safe enough, but for the option that's just swipe+tap, I'd like to confirm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The much simpler approach is to use the `UITableView` delegate support to know when you are about to enter single row editing.  The `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` delegate call occurs BEFORE calling `setEditing:animated:` which allows you to avoid any normal edit setup such as creating an insert row, etc.  The `tableView:willEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:` is called AFTER setEditing:animated.

So the code is as simple as:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.singleRowDeleteMode = YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.singleRowDeleteMode = NO;
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if (self.singleRowDeleteMode) { return; }
    // Continue setup of normal edit mode
}
```

Comment: The answer saves a lot of my time! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. Subclass UITableViewCell and add this property to its h. file:

> @property (nonatomic) UITableViewCellStateMask cellEditingState;

2. In your custom cell, on its m. file, add the following override:

> ```
> -(void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
> {
>     [super willTransitionToState:state];
>     self.cellEditingState = state;
> }
> ```

3. And now, in your UITableView's delegate, when you override

> -(void)tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:

you can identify the scenario of which the delete button was tapped after it was shown using swipe to left, by checking:

```
    YourCustomCellClass *cell = (YourCustomCellClass *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    BOOL shouldReturnToNoneEditingMode = (cell.cellEditingState == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple specifically designed the deletion mode to require 2 gestures. In edit mode you have to:

1. Press the delete button on the left.
2. Press the delete button on the right.

In non-edit mode you have to:

1. Swipe the cell.
2. Press the delete button on the right.

Adding a third validation step is overkill and leads to a bad user experience.

Comment: I agree, but I'm not a UX designer, so I have to make these things work ;)

Comment: Tell your UX designer to quit their day job. I added another answer that should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is add a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isTableViewEditing;
```

When the Edit button is pushed, and you enter editing mode, set this property to match that value. When you receive the call to `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` you can use this property to see if it was called from a swipe or if you're in editing mode.